# twitter share button typo

Tags: php, html, twitter

I put a twitter button in my site, but there is a weird typo there:
[image]

The code for the button:

```
<a  
        lang="<?php echo mida_is_english() ? 'es' : 'he' ?>"
        href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet"      
        class="twitter-share-button"
        data-url="<?php echo esc_url( wp_get_shortlink() ); ?>"
        data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>"   
        style="position: static; visibility: visible; <?php echo mida_is_english() ? 'width: 62px;' : 'width: 50px;' ?> height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom;"></a>
```

Link to that page:
http://mida.org.il/2016/03/03/no-global-cop-the-victims-of-obamas-appeasment/

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you send link of that page.

Comment: I put a link to that post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, it's because you're using es as your language code. Lang makes the button internationalized, but `es` is the language code for Spanish, not English. English is `en`